# Why do Unix/Linux systems still need to depend on Microsoft?

Tags: windows, uefi, file-types

On an Ubuntu 20.04 system on Intel hardware:

```
# cd /boot/efi/EFI/
# file $(find . -name '*.efi')
./ubuntu/grubx64.efi: PE32+ executable …, for MS Windows
./ubuntu/shimx64.efi: PE32+ executable …, for MS Windows
./ubuntu/mmx64.efi:   PE32+ executable …, for MS Windows
./BOOT/fbx64.efi:     PE32+ executable …, for MS Windows
./BOOT/mmx64.efi:     PE32+ executable …, for MS Windows
```

It is Ubuntu-only, single-boot.
Unix systems predate Windows by fourteen years.

So why "MS Windows"?

Is there no way of escaping from the world of Microsoft?

(And yes, I know, resistance is futile.)

Comment: Linux isn't any more dependent on Microsoft, than AMD is on Intel.

Comment: That's not what that means, and you're misunderstanding what you're reading.

Comment: @Shadur, right.  As I said earlier in a comment on the accepted answer: "*It sounds like my real problem is with the `file` program's reporting of these files as being '**for** MS Windows'*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PE32+ is a [public specification](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format) that was chosen for a reason (see the note on page 15 of the [UEFI Specification 2.8B](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI%20Spec%202.8B%20May%202020.pdf)).

> Note:This image type is chosen to enable UEFI images to contain Thumb and Thumb2 instructions while defining the EFI interfaces themselves to be in ARM mode)

It has nothing to do with *dependency*. Many specifications were developed by a company and then adopted as standards. For more info on the competing formats you could start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_executable_file_formats).

Comment: It sounds like my real problem is with the `file` program's reporting of these files as being "**for** MS Windows".